# Why doesn't the jQuery script set the width of an element?

Tags: jquery, width

James here. I'm working on a site that I want to have the same number of posts no matter what the screen resolution. I'm trying to use this script, but it's not working. It SHOULD get the width of the page document, subtract 400px, divide that number by 4, and then set the CSS of the element .entry to that math equation. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong? I'm new to jQuery, so it's surprising I was able to even get this far.

EDIT: I solved my problem using this code in the end:

```
$(function() {
            var cwidth = $(document).width() - 100;
            var pwidth = cwidth - 150;
            var ewidth = (pwidth - 150)/5;
            $("#container").css("width", cwidth);
                $("#posts").css("width", pwidth);
                $(".entry").css("width", ewidth);
                $(".photo").css("width", ewidth);
});
```

So thank you all quite a bit for helping. However, I've ran into a few more problems. For some reason even though the script divides by 5, there are only 4 posts per row and the posts overflow out of the div they're in. Example: http://jamescharless.tumblr.com/ - I think this is because the div the entries are in doesn't have a width set in the CSS since it's added with jQuery. Does anyone know how to fix this? Also, I tried implementing masonry by David Desandro, and it just messes up the whole page. I think this is also because the div #posts and the div .entry doesn't get a width via CSS. Can anyone help me with either of these issues?

Comment: are you getting an error? if so, what is it ... check your console

Comment: @Xander - Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.. I have no clue what that means.

Comment: you forgot to include `jQuery` or you're referencing it incorrectly ... `$` is the alias for the `jQuery` function ...

Comment: @Xander - WOW, I am so stupid! I added it now, but it's still not working.

Comment: change `$("document")` to `$(document)` and it should work ...

Comment: @Xander I did. It's still not working, I have no clue why.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9545/discussion-between-jamescharless-and-xander)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do:

```
$(document).width()
```

Not

```
$("document").width()
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WsZry/

```
$(function() {
    width = ($(document).width()-400)/4;
    $(".entry").css("width", width);
})​;
```

As `document` isn't a HTML element, it's a JavaScript property.

Comment: Same goes for `$(window)`, too.

Comment: Oh, duh! I did change it though, still doesn't work. I updated the question with a page I'm trying to get this to work on.

Comment: @JamesCharless - Firebug is indicating you need a `;` at the end of the `$()` part, although I'm not sure why, it shouldn't be required.

Comment: @JamesCharless you need to add a semi colon at the end:
`$(function() { ... });` <-- add that last semi colon
Not entirely sure why but that fixes it for me - updated my answer too.

Comment: @JackFranklin YAY! That fixed it! Thanks you rock! :)

Comment: @JamesCharless - Actually, you need to move the `<script>` tag that's between `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<html>` into the `<head>` tag. This isn't valid and the (non-)error goes away when this happens. Use the `;`, though. It's good practice.

Comment: Ah good spot @JaredFarrish, that's a much better solution :) Thanks.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I can't remove that script, it's implemented automatically. It's not doing anything to effect the document. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You quoted the `document` inside double quotes `$("document")`

```
$(function() {
    var width = ($(document).width() - 400)/4;
    $(".entry").css("width", width);
});
```

Comment: @JamesCharless, I was wrong see the update. I have tested it.

Answer (score 0):

try removing quotes around document. try below code

```
    $(function() {
       var width = ($(document).width() - 400)/4;
       $(".entry").css("width", width);
    })
```

Comment: I did, still doesn't work. I updated the question with a page I'm trying to get this to work on.